# Convert plain text URLs to HTML hyperlinks in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a text area into which users enter a lot of text that potentially includes hyperlinks. How can I display the text and have the URLs automatically appear as hyperlinks? Is there a gem, plugin, or existing method that does this? I'm looking to be able to do something like:
 `<%=h @my_object.description.with_links %>` in my view.

Comment: with some extras: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22442375/escape-non-html-tags-in-plain-text-convert-plain-text-to-html/22442376#22442376

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Rails 4+**

Auto-linking has been removed from Rails and has been made into the [`rails_autolink`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/auto_link) gem.

```ruby
require 'rails_autolink'

auto_link("Go to http://www.rubyonrails.org and say hello to david@loudthinking.com")
# => "Go to <a href=\"http://www.rubyonrails.org\">http://www.rubyonrails.org</a> and
#     say hello to <a href=\"mailto:david@loudthinking.com\">david@loudthinking.com</a>"
```

---

**Rails 3**

Use the provided helper method called [`auto_link`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/auto_link), which is part of ActionView.

```erb
<%=h auto_link(@my_object.description) %>
```

Comment: You may be careful using this. It generates html_safe text. That means if you text to convert is something like : "hello <br/>www.google.fr</div></div>" you will get a surprise (and a security hole of course)

Comment: To add to Marcel's comment the Sanitize gem can help with selective removal of HTML.

Comment: Looks like its no longer available. The link that you have in your answer is not pointing to the right page.

Comment: Removed from Rails 3.1 and packaged into [auto_link](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) gem

Answer (score 2):

See [rinku](https://github.com/vmg/rinku) gem, which is apparently faster and more accurate than [autolink](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) gem