# Parse URLs in comments into links

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, security

I am building my own blog in Rails. One thing I would like to do is convert urls in comments into actual links.

I am not sure how to do this without opening up the page to injection.

Is there a library/plugin (or technique I am not thinking of) that does this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apparently there's a gem to do that in Rails 3.1+ `rails_autolink`

More info in this thread : 
[Replacing the 'auto_link' method in Ruby on Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418710/replacing-the-auto-link-method-in-ruby-on-rails-3-1)
https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink

If it's Rails 3.0 and down, then use the `auto_link` helper that is explained here :
[Convert plain text URLs to HTML hyperlinks in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095230/convert-plain-text-urls-to-html-hyperlinks-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: Thanks, I am using 3.2 I will check this out.

Comment: Awesome, I can even pass a hash with attributes to set on the links like: `auto_link text, :html => {:rel => 'no follow', :target => '_blank'}`